# Can't see emails older than one year in Outlook 2010

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

I'm using Outlook 2010 on my office and home computer and have setup my email as IMAP on both.

I can't see emails older than one year.

I have tried to check the setting on both computers but can't figure out why. I don't want to archive or lose my old emails unless I delete them manually.

Comment: Are you sure the messages still are on the server? The server might have been set up to archive them automatically. Have you tried other IMAP clients (Thunderbird, Windows Live Mail)?

Comment: Maybe there is a filter applied? In your inbox click on the "View" ribbon and select the "Reset View" button, or click the "View Settings" button and see if any filters are applied.

Comment: I'm using outlook 2016 with office 365 and the inbox only shows items less than a year old. there's a notification at the bottom saying "There are more items in this folder on the server - click here to view more on Microsoft Exchange". When I click that the other items appear but sooner or later they go again and the notification comes back.

Answer (score 3):

Outlook 2010 uses the Auto Archive feature to keep Outlook running smoothly. It automatically stores old items outside of the Outlook Data file which meet the settings criteria you were looking at. It does not delete them (unless you choose to do so). It only store them in a seperate location.

To access archived items and to learn more about how to use it, here is more detailed [information](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/open-and-find-items-in-an-archive-outlook-data-file-pst-HA010356517.aspx).

Comment: CharlieRB, I think http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2733062 is a good complement to you answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have auto archiving enabled? Which archives old mails to a seperate folder? This is not normal behaviour of outlook. 
You should provide more info or look into the settings.